# Array Find() method is always returning 'undefined' while searching data with respect to URL parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to show the data from the array of whole data which should satisfy the condition that the requested id matches with the id of the data. But every time I try the below code, I only get 'undefined' as an output from the find method.

**Code**

---

```
    import express from 'express';
    import data from "./data.js"
    
    const app=express(); 
    app.get('/products/api/:id',(req,res)=>{
        const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id === req.params.id);
          if (product) {
               res.send(product)
          }
          else{
              res.status(404).send({message:`Product Not Found${req.params.id}`});
          }
      }) app.get('/products/api',(req,res)=>{
        res.send(data.products) 
      }) app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.send("server is ready") 
      }) const port=process.env.PORT || 5000 app.listen(5000,()=>{
        console.log(`serve at http://localhost:${port}`);
     })
```

Comment: This code does not use `.find()` anywhere

Comment: Did you mean filter() instead of find()?

Comment: Hi if you mean filter instead of find than make sure that id coming for request and from data array both are of same datatype as you are using === (strict condition) means 1 === '1' is false it should be 1 === 1 else use ==, hope this help you.

Comment: yes sorry I have uploaded the wrong code its find instead of filter and  I have updated it.

Comment: I have found the answer to it  ` const h=parseInt(req.params.id)
    const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id ===h );`

Comment: If it returns `undefined` then it doesn't match. We can't tell why it doesn't match because we can't see either the data nor the URL you are entering to search with.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing body parsing middleware.
Try adding an

`app.use(express.json({ extended: true }))` before your routes.

Also please check if the `id` from `data.products.find((x) => x.id === req.params.id);` is of type `string`. It might be a `number` or an `ObjectId` mongoose object id.

Comment: Why would that matter? The code isn't trying to access `req.body`. The data it is reading is in the URL not the body.

Comment: You might be right, still he's going to need it at some point. Anyway I edited my answer to include the other possibility of why this might be failing.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is,

change this:

```
const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id === req.params.id);
```

to:

```
const product = data.products.find((x) => x.id == req.params.id);
```